# How to download a video from url using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, download, youtube

I would like to download and store videos given the url of that video (i.e.: youtube) using MATLAB. Any idea where I can start or if there already exist some function that does this?

Comment: youtube video are in flash format (or whatever format they are in now..) Matlab only supports certain format (depending on your version number) check here: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-video-file-formats.html. This tool box allows you to load video from URL http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8028-mmread

Comment: Search an implementation in Java or python and call it in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Mat,
There is currently no functionality shipping with MATLAB that allows you to read videos from youtube into MATLAB.